# NodeStream, Sequelize and Big Data

Tags: sequelize.js, bigdata, node-streams

I have an application that returns almost 20 thousand records, I was advised to use NodeStream and until "yesterday", everything was ok. Now I have 30 thousand items and it is causing memory problems again on the node.

I wanted to understand, how could this code work until now? If you think about it, shouldn't the return of Sequelize already break the variable, as it has more than 20 thousand results?

```
const { count, rows: parcelas } = await Parcela.getParcela().findAndCountAll(queryParams);
```

Full code:

````
   const { count, rows: parcelas } = await Parcela.getParcela().findAndCountAll(queryParams);

        class StreamFromParcela extends Readable {
            constructor(array) {
                super({ objectMode: true });
                this.array = array;
                this.index = 0;
            }

            _read() {
                if (this.index < this.array.length) {
                    const parcela = this.array[this.index];
                    this.push(parcela);
                    this.index += 1;
                } else {
                    this.push(null);
                }
            }
        }

        const streamParcela = new StreamFromParcela(parcelas);

        let firstChunk = true;
        let isFirstObject = true;
        streamParcela.on('data', (chunk) => {
            if (!firstChunk) {
                res.write(',');
            }
            firstChunk = false;

            if (isFirstObject) {
                res.write('{"parcelas": [');
                isFirstObject = false;
            }

            res.write(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(chunk)));
            
        });

        streamParcela.on('end', () => {
            res.write(`],"total": ${count}}`);
            res.end();
        });```




I tried several approaches, only the code above worked.
````

Comment: You need to get the first chunk of records using `offset` and `limit` in `findAndCountAll` and it will be the first chunk for the stream and once the records in this chunk will be all transferred  you need to read the next chunk changing `offset` and calling `findAndCountAll` until you get zero records.

Comment: Traditional way is to use `server-side paging` approach when a client requests N records starting from M record number and gets `rows` and `count`